# Formatting an adjacent cell based on the content of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I believe this is probably an easy macro; it does not appear to be possible with conditional formatting and I have limited experience with macros.

I have many rows in an Excel workbook.  What I'd like to is say:

> If I place a `<` sign in the currently selected cell, then cell immediately to the right should format as bold, otherwise, it should not be emboldened.

I have fooled around with different "IF" statements, but I think I'm way off base.

How in the world do I do this?

### EDIT

Here is perhaps a better way to show this, because for some reason I still cannot get it to work; I've included a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of What I'm Working On]

(Actually, I realized that I asked the question backwards...it should be that if there if there is a cell with a "<" sign then the cell immediately to the right should **not** be bold).

Anyways, let's focus on row 12 for the sake of an example.  It would be nice to have a formula to apply to the entire row that says "look at cell C12.  If there is nothing in it, then D12 is emboldened.  Look at cell E12, if there is nothing in it then F12 should be emboldened, etc.  Look at cell Q12.  If it has a "<" sign, then R12 should not be emboldened".  The only exception to this would be cells that contain a "--"...those do not need to be emboldened.

Comment: Condition formatting works. Say I want F1 to be the formatted text when D1 is "<".  I would use the following formula in the conditional formatting for F1 `=D1="<"`

Comment: Can I extend this formula to multiple cells?

Comment: Certainly in the manage rules you would fill in the "applies to:" area with the desired cells. if you make the top one correct it will automatically make the changes to references automatically like autofill.  so if you do not want something to change put a "$" in front.

Comment: copy down a range if you want before setting the conditional formatting of the range. Then in your formula rule, reference the active cell of the selected range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CF, select the range of cells to apply the formatting to - say Columns B:M (not A because that has no "immediately to the *left*") - HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1="<"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Bold, OK, OK.

**Edit** By "those do not need to be emboldened" I take it you don't mind if they are. That might allow you to embolden the entire sheet (or rather ColumnsC:X) and apply a single *conditional* format. However that would result in the `<` themselves being emboldened and I take it you would prefer not. So if formatting is to be applied according to two separate conditions two separate rules are required. Select Columns D:X and for *bold**:

```
=C1=""
```

For Regular, with the same range selection:

```
=C1="<"
```

Comment: I've updated the question so that it is a bit more clear.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it is an easy macro. And @Scott Craner is correct as well; conditional formatting will work. However, there are times when you already have a lot of conditional formatting and adding another rule becomes a bit tricky, so here is the macro. Put it in the ThisWorkbook section.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "<" Then
        Sh.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, you can make your own little formatting rules by checking the value of the cell that changed.

To learn more, search up "Learn Excel". Plenty of resources.

Comment: I appreciate the help...it seems as if everyone has a different way to do macros.  For example, what are the arguments you're putting in parentheses (ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)?

Comment: Those are the standard variables that are needed for the `Workbook_SheetChange` event. They are added automatically by Excel when you select that event in the IDE dropdowns.. `Sh` is the sheet that is changing and `Target` is the range that is changing.